# $ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega_\varepsilon} f_n\leq\int_{\Omega_\varepsilon} f $ implies that of $\Omega$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n,f\in L^1(\Omega)$, all non-negative. Let $\Omega_\varepsilon$ be an increasing set sequence that $\bigcup_{\varepsilon>0}\Omega_\varepsilon=\Omega$. If for each $\varepsilon$,

$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega_\varepsilon} f_n\leq\int_{\Omega_\varepsilon} f
$

Do we have
$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\Omega} f_n\leq\int_{\Omega} f
?$

Comment: What kind of assumptions do you have on $\Omega$? Is it a bounded open set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $\Omega =(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure and $\Omega_{\epsilon} =(\epsilon ,1)$. Let $f_n=nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$, $f=0$. For each $\epsilon$ we have $\int_{\Omega_{\epsilon}} f_n=0$ as soon as $\frac 1 n <\epsilon$ but $\int_{\Omega} f_n=1$ for all $n$.